# How to find the usage of a jar imported by maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Java project source code.
It imported a jar library by maven dependency.I want to find where does this project used the method or class provided by the jar library.
How can i do this?

Remove the jar and see the compiler error can do this,but it cant show all usages,compiling will stop when it found an error.Any other way?

Comment: you can search the package name used by the library in all project files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comment, you can open the dependency to get  the package name, for example:

[image]

then use the default short cut  <kbd>ctrl shift f</kbd>  and enter the package name for global search:

[image]