# IntelliJ IDEA: How to get the usages of a maven dependency?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Is there a better way to get the usages of a maven dependency in the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA than [How to find the usage of a jar imported by maven dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51908144/how-to-find-the-usage-of-a-jar-imported-by-maven-dependency) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is not yet implemented. Feel free to upvote for [IDEA-51267](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-51267).

However, you can expand the jar file and select packages inside of it. Then choose `Find Usages`:

[image]